# laravel fcm push notification with brozot/Laravel-FCM not working on ios but working fine with android

Tags: ios, firebase, laravel-5, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

Even ios can get notification from fcm console.

**Controller function**:

```
public function push(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'title' = > 'required',
            'body' = > 'required',
            'token' = > 'required',
            'type' = > 'required',
            'id' = > 'required',

    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $title = $request['title'];
    $body = $request['body'];
    $type = $request['type'];
    $id = $request['id'];
    $dataarray = array(
        "id" = >$id,
        "type" = >$type,
        'title' = >$title,
        'body' = >$body,
        'image' = >'321451_v2.jpg',
    );

    $token = $request['token'];

    return $push = Push::sendpush($title, $body, $dataarray, $token);

}

push model function :
public static function sendpush($title, $body, $dataarray, $token)
{


    $optionBuiler = new OptionsBuilder();
    $optionBuiler->setTimeToLive(60 * 20);

    $notificationBuilder = new PayloadNotificationBuilder($title);
    $notificationBuilder->setBody($body)
        ->setSound('');

    $dataBuilder = new PayloadDataBuilder();
    $dataBuilder->addData($dataarray);

    $option = $optionBuiler->build();
    $notification = $notificationBuilder->build();
    $data = $dataBuilder->build();

    $token = $token;

    $downstreamResponse = FCM::sendTo($token, $option, $notification, $data);

    return new JsonResponse(array('status' = >'1', 'sucess' = >$downstreamResponse->numberSuccess(), 'fail' = > $downstreamResponse->numberFailure(), 'msg' = >$downstreamResponse->tokensWithError()), 200);

}

Response:
{
    "status": "1",
    "sucess" : 0,
    "fail" : 1,
    "msg" : []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying using ios simulator it will not work. You need to use some tools like testflight or real device to test.

can we check push notification in simulator?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up a certificate for Ios follow this link to see more details
[Configuring APNs with FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/certs)

or see this [Set up a Firebase Cloud Messaging client app on iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)