# Laravel FCM push notification with Firebase not working on iOS, but fine with Android

Tags: php, firebase, laravel-5.3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried Firebase notification with Laravel to send notification to IOS and Android devices.

But IOS device not received the notifications but Android devices working good.

So what is the issue in my script?

**I have tried following,**

```
$firebase = new \Firebase();
$push = new \Push();

// optional payload

$payload = array();
$payload['team'] = 'India';
$payload['score'] = '5.6';

// notification title
$title = Input::get('title');
// notification message

$message = Input::get('message');

// push type - single user / topic
$push_type = Input::get('push_type');

// whether to include to image or not
$include_image = Input::get('include_image') ? TRUE : FALSE;
$include_image = TRUE;
$push->setTitle($title);
$push->setMessage($message);

if ($include_image) {
   $push->setImage('http://api.androidhive.info/images/minion.jpg');
} else {
   $push->setImage('');
}
$push->setIsBackground(FALSE);
$push->setPayload($payload); 

$json = '';
$response = '';

if ($push_type == 'topic') {
   $json = $push->getPush();
   $response = $firebase->sendToTopic('global', $json);
} else if ($push_type == 'individual') {
   $json = $push->getPush();
   $regId = Input::get('regId');
   $response = $firebase->send($regId, $json);
}
```

I have refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42292598/laravel-fcm-push-notification-with-brozot-laravel-fcm-not-working-on-ios-but-wor) but there is no answer provided.

Comment: Hi KAR. Have you tried setting the payload `priority` to `high`?

Comment: Let me check. @AL.

Comment: still not working. @AL.

Comment: Could you post the payload structure that is sent out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a 'notification' json block for iOS to respond

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

$token = "";

$serverKey = '';

$title = "Title";

$body = "Body of the message";

$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');

$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);

$headers = array();

$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';

$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,

"POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
//Send the request

$response = curl_exec($ch);
//Close request

if ($response === FALSE) {

die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));

}
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: please write some description for your answer too.